# How to get a name of the clicked <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code :

```
<div class="span4">
<div class="hero-unit" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                North Delhi
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <ol>
                        <li><a id='link' href="#" name="Some name1 ">Some link1</a> </li>
                        <li><a id='link' href="#" name="Some name2">Some link2</a> </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr(name); //alerts undefined
        alert(n);
        $('#results').html('&nbsp;').load('/donate/?n=' + n);
    });
});
```

My HTML code has several accordion-inner divs with multiple links. I want to get the name attribute of the clicked link. This code alerts me undefined check my jQuery code and please tell me what am i doing wrong?

I am new to jquery so please help.

Comment: html id attributes have to be unique. If you want to have several elements with 'link', make that a class. `class="link"` instead of `id="link"`

Comment: @nbrooks: ok so i made it class="link" and added .link in my jQuery code...but it still returns undefined.

Comment: See answers below. `name` should be in quotes, since it isn't a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not putting `name` in quotes, so Javascript looks for a *variable* named `name` and doesn't find one. You should change that to:

```
var n = $(this).attr("name");
```

Apart from that, your `id`s are not unique. This is illegal and practically guaranteed to give you problems in the future. Follow the suggestion of @nbrooks and change the overused `id` to a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes for the attribute name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#link').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr("name");   //alerts undefined <- quotes here
    alert(n);
    $('#results').html('&nbsp;').load('/donate/?n=' + n);
});
});
```

Later edit: Do not use duplicate IDs ... use class instead !

Answer (score 2):

Both your links have the same `id` attribute, which are required by the HTML spec to be unique.  jQuery is only giving you one element back.  Use a class attribute/selector combination instead:

```
<li><a class='link' href="#" name="Some name1 ">Some link1</a> </li>
<li><a class='link' href="#" name="Some name2">Some link2</a> </li>

$(".link").click(function() {
     var n1 = $(this).attr("name");  //Name should be a string here
     var n2 = this.name  //name should be a variable here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#link').click(function() {
   var n = $(this).attr("name"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first up change your li to these

```
<li><a class='link' href="#" name="Some name1 ">Some link1</a> </li>
<li><a class='link' href="#" name="Some name2">Some link2</a> </li>
```

use class instead of id, as that is a violation on CSS..

and then change your jquery to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.link').click(function() {
var n = $(this).attr('name');   //alerts undefined
alert(n);
$('#results').html('&nbsp;').load('/donate/?n=' + n);
});
});
```

use . instead of # and your set